# What does 'State xxx cannot be set as an initial Evil state' mean?

Tags: spacemacs, evil

When I try to enter a command such as `set number` in Spacemacs, I get the error `State number cannot be set as initial Evil state`.

What is an `initial evil state` and what does the error message actually mean, ie the implication?

Comment: you accepted an answer. So you solved something. What exactly did you solve and what commands did you run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:set numbers` ends up calling `evil-ex-set-initial-state` which expects an initial state, such as `normal`, `insert`, `emacs`, etc.  This command sets up the initial state the current buffer starts out with for better Emacs integration.  For example, a text editing related buffer should start in normal state, a REPL in insert state, buffers with many special keys in Emacs state, etc.

This means you're doing the wrong thing if you want to enable line numbers.  Use `M-x linum-mode` instead.  Generally, you'll want to learn a bit more about Emacs before diving in, be it with Spacemacs or not.

That aside, I'm not sure whether accepting `:set` for `:set-initial-state` isn't a bug within Evil's ex parser.  I'll have to investigate into that.

edit: The mentioned behavior comes from Evil trying to autocomplete `set` to a valid command, something Vim does as well for Ex commands.  The shortened notation is to have a clear preference what a very short command would be resolved to as there would be too many auto-completion candidates to pick from.

Comment: none of your suggestions worked. I still cannot see line numbers in my text files.

Comment: Make a new thread for this instead of hijacking an existing one with a most likely different problem.